# Is this the correct way to use a QThread?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I am looking at some github projects, where one of them did the UDPlink in the following way,
first it subclass QThread to create a class `UDPLink:public QThread`
and its constructor and deconstructor is like:

```
UDPLink::UDPLink(UDPConfiguration* config)
    : _socket(NULL)
    , _connectState(false)
{
    Q_ASSERT(config != NULL);
    _config = config;
    _config->setLink(this);

    // We're doing it wrong - because the Qt folks got the API wrong:
    // http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/
    moveToThread(this);

    // Set unique ID and add link to the list of links
    _id = getNextLinkId();
    qDebug() << "UDP Created " << _config->name();
}

UDPLink::~UDPLink()
{
    // Disconnect link from configuration
    _config->setLink(NULL);
    _disconnect();
    // Tell the thread to exit
    quit();
    // Wait for it to exit
    wait();
    this->deleteLater();
}
```

Though the code did compile and work, but I wonder whether this way of using a QThread would be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Qt developer recommended, Code you mentioned is not correct way to use QThread.

Recommended way is suggested [here](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2006/12/04/threading-without-the-headache/).

Sample code from Post.

```
Producer producer;
Consumer consumer;
producer.connect(&consumer, SIGNAL(consumed()), SLOT(produce()));
consumer.connect(&producer, SIGNAL(produced(QByteArray *)), SLOT(consume(QByteArray *)));

// they both get their own thread
QThread producerThread;
producer.moveToThread(&producerThread);
QThread consumerThread;
consumer.moveToThread(&consumerThread);

// go!
producerThread.start();
consumerThread.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

The Qt docs for QThread describe the two ways threading can be done with QThread. Sub-classing QThread was the only way to use QThread initially. To use QThread in this manner, override the run method, which is the QThread method that runs on a new thread. QThread should be thought of as a thread manager, not an object that runs on a separate thread itself. From the docs:

> It is important to remember that a QThread instance lives in the old
>   thread that instantiated it, not in the new thread that calls run().
>   This means that all of QThread's queued slots will execute in the old
>   thread. Thus, a developer who wishes to invoke slots in the new thread
>   must use the worker-object approach; new slots should not be
>   implemented directly into a subclassed QThread.
>
> When subclassing QThread, keep in mind that the constructor executes
>   in the old thread while run() executes in the new thread. If a member
>   variable is accessed from both functions, then the variable is
>   accessed from two different threads. Check that it is safe to do so.

[QThread documentation page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html)

It's because QThread is a thread manager class that a solution for moving objects to threads was created. The comment in the code you provided makes a statement about this change, since that article states that moveToThread(this) isn't a good practice.

Creating an object and moving it to a thread and sub-classing QThread are both valid approaches to threading with Qt, as the documentation now states clearly. There is a benefit to using the worker-object approach, if you desire to use signal/slot connections across thread boundaries: a worker object will have its slots available on the thread it is moved to.